Linux Fedora 40: Pycharm 'socket.timeout: timed out' with docker compose on debug
After a Linux reinstall remote debugger is not working anymore, I have done the same procedure multiple times and this is the first time it happens, it works fine on Run but it fails on Debug.
This is the output:
Attaching to mw_django
django  | PostgreSQL is available
django  | Could not connect to 172.17.0.1: 45689
django  | Traceback (most recent call last):
django  |   File "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 462, in start_client
django  |     s.connect((host, port))
django  | socket.timeout: timed out
django  | Could not connect to 172.17.0.1: 45689
django  | Traceback (most recent call last):
django  |   File "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 2243, in main
django  |     debugger.connect(host, port)
django  |   File "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 704, in connect
django  |     s = start_client(host, port)
django  |   File "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 462, in start_client
django  |     s.connect((host, port))
django  | socket.timeout: timed out

I already stopped the firewall, disabled selinux, removed all Pycharm cache, I removed all the containers data (docker system prune -a), I also tried a different project without docker and debug works just fine so there is a problem with debug on docker.
How can I fix this problem?
